# Use only the first image if there are multiples

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I want to get an understanding of how to achieve the following. I have a simple CMS that will allow you to upload portfolio information/images. The user can upload one image or multiple images.

To show each image I use a `.each` and iterate through all the images for each portfolio...

```
<!-- Project Feed -->
    <div class="project-feed clearfix">
     <% @portfolios.each do |p| %>
      <div class="one-third project-item"><!-- add data filter class here to enable selection of sectors-->

       <% p.images.each do |i| %>
        <%= image_tag(i.photo.url(:portfolio_square)) %>
         <div class="overlay">
         <!-- Small image bottom right of overlay, click and can navigate through all images 
          <%= image_tag(i.photo.url(:portfolio_large), :class => 'lightbox-link folio', :rel => 'gallery') %> -->
          <%= link_to p do %>
           <h5><%= p.title %> </h5>
          <% end %>
           <p>
          <%= p.sectors.map(&:name).join(", ") %>
          </p>
         </div><!--/overlay-->
         <h4><%= p.title %></h4>
      </div>
       <% end %>
     <% end %>
```

My problem is that if there are multiple images assigned to the portfolio (let's say Portfolio 3 has 4 images associated with it) then they all show.

So I want to achieve this layout:

```
Portfolio 1   Portfolio 2  Portfolio 3
```

as opposed to

```
 Portfolio 1   Portfolio 2  Portfolio 3

 Portfolio 3   Portfolio 3  Portfolio 3
```

How can I grab only one image if there are multiples? Would this be `.first`? though I am unsure of the syntax and how it would fit in with my code. Or would I create a separate block and put it in an if statement if the image count is more than 1?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're trying to do. Do you want the user to see the images he just uploaded instead of all the images he owns? Or you want the user to able to see the first image of the (possibly) multiple images he uploaded?

Comment: see the first image of potentially many (there's not always multiple images)

Comment: Try playing around with this line `<% p.images.each do |i| %>`. I guess it's an array, using `.last` or `.first` would be my first bet, depends how you store the pictures when uploaded.

Comment: well i tried <% p.images.first do |i| %> but no images get displayed when i use that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `first` like this:

```
<%= image_tag(p.images.first.photo.url(:portfolio_square)) %>
```

If you do this you don't need:

```
<% p.images.each do |i| %>
```

Comment: thanks for offering an answer.. this works, as does Uri Agassi's.I can see now that i dont have to iterate through the images in a separate block, just join them like you have (p.images.first.photo)..Ill mark yours as answer as you where the first to post something, plus you have helped refactor my code too :-)

Comment: You're welcome. Note that if it's possible to have portfolios without any images, you should check that `p.images.first` does not return `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to change the behavior of `p.images.each` to take only the first element, in that case, the minimal impact change on your code could be:

```
<% p.images.take(1).each do |i| %>
```